# Recording external API using mockoon

Tags: mocking, automocking, mockoon

I have just started using **Mockoon** tool and I am finding a way to record an API which is already created and running in a port like for example I have a API like http://10.12.150.25:8080/welcome which is already creating and I want to capture request and response going to that API using a **Mockoon** (I think for this we can import our swagger file and capture but I want it as live recording). as of my understating creating new environment in **Mockoon** means creating a new API.

**Queries:

Is it possible to do my use cases in Mockoon?
If yes how can I achieve that?**

Answer (score 0):

[Update 2023-11-20]
Since [version 3.1.0](https://mockoon.com/releases/3.1.0/#new-recording-mode-in-the-logs-view) a recording mode has been added.

---

There is no "automatic" recording option in Mockoon. But you can enable the proxy and from the "Logs" tab add the endpoints manually.

1. Enable the proxy:

[image]

2. Manually mock an request/response:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this github issue, unfortunately the author is not interested in implementing this:

https://github.com/mockoon/mockoon/issues/21

I was looking to do the same, but now I'm evaluating [polly.js](https://netflix.github.io/pollyjs/#/)

Comment: I answered you on the issue: https://github.com/mockoon/mockoon/issues/21
Recording was added in v3.1.0
At the time of issue #21, yes, I thought it wasn't worth the time. It was also 6 years ago. 
Since then it was requested multiple times and was finally implemented. Or maybe there is something you think is missing?